# I believe in Allah and His Messenger, but follow the teachings of Jesus; am I considered a non-believer?

Tags: non-muslim, christianity

I was raised a Christian. But I have read the Koran and believe in Allah and His Messenger. Since I also follow the teachings of Jesus, am I still considered a non-believer?

Comment: No you aren't if you are following teachings of Muhammad as well. According to Islam, anybody can't be considered a Muslim if he doesn't follow teachings of Jesus and every Muslim must follow teachings of Jesus! But you shouldn't consider Jesus as son of God and you should believe that He is not crucified and is alive in Heaven and will come back one day. If any teachings in Islam and Christianity differ, you should prefer Islamic teachings. The teachings of Jesus and Muhammad could never differ but the people who edited Bible produced differences! And we follow Jesus not editors!

Comment: If you believe in what you [said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada), then you **are** a believer no matter whom you follow.

Comment: @RehanUllah Muslim is supposed to believe in all the Prophets but to follow the teachings of Muhammad peace be upon him because as every prophet was given a shariah a system to follow like Prophet Moses a.s ummah was not supposed to pray five times but in our Ummah we have to ,they had hadd commands so which shariah we follow, their teachings are not truly saved rather adulterated so if following means character following then its good they all gave message of Allah swt but their pure teachings are not preserved adulterated so Muslim believe in all Prophets ,follow Muhammad peace be upon him

Comment: @servant Your last line is brilliant: "Muslim believe in all Prophets ,follow Muhammad peace be upon him"! I think I am trying to say the same thing in my comment. Have I done some mistake?

Comment: @RehanUllah to answer a revert your effort is good as he would not be considered as a non believer but in surah Baqarah it is mentioned that there were some munafiqoon who say we believe Muhammad peace be upon him but dont follow him when going to their community, for his question its good to clarify about following because now when Prophet Jesus peace be upon him would come again in this world he would be following same Shariah which was given to Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him.

Comment: Indeed you have to edit that "Every muslim must follow teachings of Jesus" because every muslim has to believe all holy Books and prophets but to follow means that some rulings could  be changed and then it also means that every muslim should follow bible and we all know present time its not preserved as it was revealed.

Answer (score 1):

To be Muslim you have to believe in the Shahdah. The Shahdah states that Allah is the one and only true God and Muhammad is in His Messenger.

Muslims too believe in Jesus and call him Isa (AS). Muslims believe that he was a Prophet and a Messenger of Allah and that the Bible was sent to him. The Bible which used today has been changed and therefore not reliable.

If you believe in the Shahadah then you are a Muslim (You have to say the shahadah and declare you belief when you convert) You can follow the teaching of Jesus too. However you have to be careful with the Bible (Old testament and New) as it has been altered and some things go against the teaching of Islam.